# How to debug tests from a Maven build in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven, build

How is it possible to start a Maven build and let the tests appear in the debug perspective of Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A package or install is meant to be an atomic action that really shouldn't be stopped for debugging (unless you're debugging a maven plug-in).  You ought to be able to debug the tests by selecting the Eclipse project and doing a "Debug As -> JUnit Test", though.

Comment: Your solution has an advantage over mine: I can see the execution flow in decompiled classes, which doesn't work with my Maven command line soluton

Comment: In my case there is no other solution as eclipse test is working but maven is failing

Answer (score 2):

How to configure it:

- Create a new Java project in Eclipse. Let's call it "Maven debugger project". It's a dummy project and is not intented to contain any code.
- Create a new debug configuration. Let's call it "Maven debug launch". In the Connect tab, enter "localhost" in the Host field and "5005" in the Port field, which is the port where the Surefire plugin communicates with a debugger. Choose "Standard (Socket Attach)" in Connection Type. In the Source tab, add the projects you want to debug.

How to use it:

- You can now set breakpoints in your test code.
- Start your "Maven debug launch" in debug
- Start your Maven build with the "`-Dmaven.surefire.debug`" option

I found that interesting solution [here](http://www.homik.de/think/index.php/2008/07/31/debugging-maven-projects-with-eclipse/), and it was useful to me (which mean I tested it, and it worked), so I wanted to share it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the Maven build with the Ecplise Maven Plugin :

- Place the debug point in java code
- Right click on your pom.xml or your project in Eclipse and Select "Debug As" and then "Maven Install" or If you want an other Maven goal Select "Maven build..."

Comment: @Traroth And how do you know it's not working? Not that I don't believe you, but the symptoms will help understand

Comment: @ChrisGerken: As I said, it's the first thing I tried. The symptoms are simple: it behaves exactly as if launched with Run, which means the execution flow doesn't stop at breakpoints.

Comment: Can you try to debug it as JUnit test as I suggest in my answer?