# How to 'run maven test' in debug mode in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging, testing

I have a maven project with java source code.  I use the menu item `run maven test` to execute the test code.  I set a few break points on some of the classes and tried `debug maven test`, but the system did not stop at the break points.

Are there any additional configuration steps I have to do in order to run test code in debug mode?  I have verified the execution did pass by the lines where the break points were, by adding `System.out` statements.

Also I can debug this project when I run it as a java application.

I am using Eclipse Neon, JDK 1.8, if this matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug tests from a Maven build in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359796/how-to-debug-tests-from-a-maven-build-in-eclipse)

Comment: Why not running the test itself directly via "Right Click on  the appropriate Test" -> "Debug As" -> "Junit Test" in your IDE instead from Maven if you really need to debug a test?

Comment: The problem is that the tests were written in cucumber feature file format (a text file, parse/execute by a java test runner), and I don't see a way I can 'debug' the test file.  Based on the first comment, it appears there is no way to debug a 'run maven test' process?  Which is kind of strange because it is one of the available options under the 'debug' menu.

Comment: You have to set the property `maven.surefire.debug=true`. See [here](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#automatically-launch-and-attach-remote-application-debugger-when-maven-plug-in-starts-a-forked-jvm-that-waits-for-a-debugger) ([video](https://youtu.be/GnNnQY5ujFg?feature=shared)).